# variadic template for forward list initialization of std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a geometry structure describing a point in N dimensions

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class point : public std::array<T, N>
```

Among the many constructors / methods I'd like to add to this class, I cannot figure out how to build a variadic constructor. I've tried

```
template<typename ...Args>
point(Args&&...t) : std::array<T,N>(std::forward<Args>(t)...)
{
}
```

but that doesn't work

```
std::array<int,5> p1 = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3}; // OK
point<int,5>      p2 = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3}; // ERROR
```

how can I define such a constructor ?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a constructor taking `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: What is your question? The last snippet should compile, combine that with `std::forward` and you have your original desired constructor.

Comment: The last part is me answering my own question

Comment: @Amxx Then you should post it as an answer. The reason you need to use braces instead of parentheses is because `std::array` is an aggregate and has no user defined constructors, so you must perform aggregate initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour comes from the specificity of `std::array`. Being an agregate without common constructor means you can't initialize it using `std::forward` or `std::initializer_list`

On should rather use double braces like so:

```
template<typename ...Args>
point(Args&&... args) : std::array<T,N>{{args...}}
```